# PHP requires quotes to use "Transaction" table in SQL Server database

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

In ms sql server i have a table its name is "Transaction" and I know i have to put "" sign on Transaction Table to select table  using sql query what i mean is
if i use

```
select SalesTax
from "Transaction"
where Total = 59.00
```

Then it works

but if i use

```
select SalesTax
from Transaction
where Total = 59.00
```

Then it doesn't work

what i am wondering about is in php script to select table still php doesn't recognize transaction table i tried 'Transaction' and "Transaction" too but it doesn't work anybody have a idea?
the below is the php script i have used to update ..

```
$tsql = "UPDATE Transaction SET Quantity = (Quantity - $qty)
         WHERE ItemLookupCode = '$sku'";
```

Thank you so much guys in advance....

Comment: Give us more codes about this particular query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server, reserved words can be escaped using square brackets `[]`.

So you can try:

```
$tsql = "UPDATE [Transaction] 
         SET Quantity = (Quantity - $qty) 
         WHERE ItemLookupCode = '$sku'";
```

*Note: you should not name tables, etc with reserved words for this exact reason.*

Comment: It should also be possible to use `"UPDATE \"Transaction\" ..."`.